# Prettier code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a prettier version for this snippet of code?

```
@available_option_types.delete_if {|ot|
  result = true 
  result = current_user.retailer.id != ot.retailer.id if ot.retailer.present? 
  result
} unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@available_option_types.delete_if { |ot|
  ot.retailer.present? ? (current_user.retailer.id != ot.retailer.id) : true
} unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
```

Or it would be even prettier if you put some logic into the model:

```
class User
  def same_retailer_with?(option_type)
    option_type.retailer.present? ? (self.retailer.id != option_type.retailer.id) : true
  end
end

@available_option_types.delete_if { |ot| current_user.same_retailer_with?(ot) } unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
  @available_option_types.delete_if do |ot|
    !ot.retailer.present? ||
      (ot.retailer.present? &&
        current_user.retailer.id != ot.retailer.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@available_option_types.delete_if do |ot|
  !ot.retailer.present? || current_user.retailer.id != ot.retailer.id
end unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
```

or

```
@available_option_types.select do |ot|
  ot.retailer.present? && current_user.retailer.id == ot.retailer.id
end unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work if retailer :has_many option_types

```
@available_option_types = current_user.retailer.options_types unless current_user.has_role? 'admin'
```